# rails_admin how to make a column sortable and queryable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have stuggled with this for days and tried everything I could think of. Trying to modify an application created by someone else using **rails_admin**. All I want to do is make a field, `Course` in the list view to be alphabetically sortable and queryable. I have a model `home_study_registration`.

- HomeStudyRegistration inherits from ClassRegistration
- class_registration has_one :course, :through => :course_class
- :course_class  is an abstract model which belongs_to :course
- :course has a string attribute `:title` which now displays in the table and, when clicked navigates to the *show* view of that course.

The latter is what I'm trying to modify. Is there any way to make this column sortable? Also, how can I add a filter to search by the `:title` attribute? This is my `home_study_registration.rb` model:

```
class HomeStudyRegistration < ClassRegistration
  default_scope { joins(:course_class, :course, :user).where('course_classes.class_type = ?', "home").readonly(false) }

  delegate :full_name, :email, :profession, :ce_state, :ce_number, :to => :user, :prefix => true
  delegate :eacc, :to => :course_class
  delegate :title, :to => :course

  RailsAdmin.config do |config|
    config.model HomeStudyRegistration do 
      navigation_label 'Course Management'
      parent HomeStudy
      label 'Manage Home Study'

      list do
        sort_by :created_at
        filters [:created_at, :status]

        field :user do
          label 'name'
          column_width 120
        end

        field :cart do
          label 'order'
          column_width 50
        end
        field :user_ce_state do
          label 'Lic. St.'
          column_width 25
          pretty_value do
            if bindings[:object].licenses.any?
              bindings[:object].licenses.order(:created_at).collect{ |l| l.state }.join("<br>").html_safe
            else
              bindings[:object].user_ce_state
            end
          end
        end
        field :user_profession do
          label 'Lic. Type'
          column_width 100
          pretty_value do
            if bindings[:object].licenses.any?
              bindings[:object].licenses.order(:created_at).collect{ |l| l.show_profession }.join("<br>").html_safe
            else
              bindings[:object].user_profession
            end
          end
        end
        field :user_ce_number do
          label 'Lic. '
          column_width 80
          pretty_value do
            if bindings[:object].licenses.any?
              bindings[:object].licenses.order(:created_at).collect{ |l| l.number }.join("<br>").html_safe
            else
              bindings[:object].user_ce_number
            end 
          end
        end
        field :eacc do
          column_width 60
        end
        field :course do
          label 'Course' 
          column_width 200
        end
        field :score do
          column_width 55
        end
        field :status, :enum do
          column_width 55
          enum do
            ['Active', 'Completed', 'Expired', 'Errors']
          end
        end
        field :exam_completed_at do
          label 'Completed'
        end
        field :created_at do
          label 'registered'
        end

      end

      edit do
        field :course_class do
          associated_collection_scope do
                # bindings[:object] & bindings[:controller] are available, but not in scope's block!
                Proc.new { |scope|
                  scope = scope.where(class_type: "home")
                }
            end
        end
        field :user
        field :status, :enum do
          enum do
            ['Active', 'Completed', 'Expired', 'Errors']
          end
        end
        field :exam_completed_at do
          label 'Completed'
        end
        field :exam_attempts
        field :score
      end

      export do
        field :user_full_name
        field :user_email
        field :cart_id do
          label 'Order'
        end
        field :user_ce_state do
          label 'Lic. state'
        end
        field :user_profession do
          label 'Lic. type'
        end
        field :user_ce_number do
          label 'Lic. #'
        end
        field :eacc
        field :course_title
        field :score
        field :status
        field :exam_completed_at do
          label 'Completed'
        end
        field :created_at do
          label 'Registered'
        end
      end    
    end
  end
end
```

If necessary, I can abbreviate this. But I thought it may be helpful to show the context of the other methods and fields. The area I've been focusing on has been:

```
...

list do
        sort_by :created_at
        filters [:created_at, :status]

...

        field :course do
          label 'Course' 
          column_width 200
        end

...
```

I've tried adding `sortable: true` and `sortable :title` and all variations of filterable tag and "pretty_value" bindings. This problem has drastically shortened my life. Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: I have not used rails_admin before. I am guessing it has its own methods for sorting columns? What is the data inside the course column look like? What data type is it?

Comment: Thanks @Lumbee, the column displays the `:title` attribute for Course model, which is a string. Yeah the rails_admin DSL is really abstract and a lot of the documentation contradicts itself. I'm actually able to get `sortable` working on the column now by adding a line `sortable {:title}` in the "field course do" block, which FYI is not in *any* of the syntaxes described in the docs. Go figure. Unfortunately can't get searchable/queryable working because adding a similar tag produces a PG error (undefined "FROM"). Probably because *Course* is grandchild of *ClassRegistration*. Frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

```
field :course do
      label 'Course' 
      column_width 200
      sortable "courses.name" #courses.lastname or courses.firstname
  end
```